# sed doesn't accept my variable to parse a file

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, config, seq

I'm trying to read this config file :

```
#[TABLE]
pattern1
DISK_MAIN
PART_EFI
PART_SWAP
PART_ROOT
pattern2
#[END_TABLE]
... rest of the file
```

I figured i had to use sed but so i researched on how to do it and saw this example :

```
val1="pattern1"
val2="pattern2"
sed -n "/^$val1/,/^$val2/p;/^$val2/q" $file
```

but once i change val1 and val2 to another thing it doesn't work anymore, i thought it was the special characters so i removed the #[] but it done noting can someone help me, I'm terrible at understanding regex stuff with my dyslexia ( it's also hard for me to go trough heavy documentation, that's why i ask that kind of stuff ).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "i change val1 and val2 to another thing" -- what other thing? What was the new value of those variables?

Answer (score 1):

You were correct that a `[` in the pattern affects the match, because it is a regex metacharacter. (`#` is not a problem, and `]` is only special after `[`.) But you can't just remove them, because your pattern starts with `^`, which means that it must match at the beginning of the line, and the beginning of the line is precisely `#` followed by `[`.

So you need to tell sed to ignore the meaning of the `[`, which you do by placing a `\` before it. However, you can't just add a `\` to your command, because `\` is a special character for the shell (meaning that the next character has no special meaning, just like it does in sed.)

So in order to get it to work, you need to put *two* `\` before the `[`, leaving you with:

```
pattern1='#\\[TABLE]'
pattern2='#\\[END_TABLE]'
sed -n "/^$pattern1/,/^$pattern2/p;/$pattern2/q;" "$file"
```

That might need to be adjusted if there are other special characters in the patterns. I'm just taking the patterns out of your comment to a different answer, although it would be better if you put the real patterns in your question, which would make it possible to answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry to answer 7 day after but i tried your solution but it didn't work. i changed the hardquote ' for pattern1 and pattern2 into " and it worked.

Comment: Oops, sorry. But it seems like you got the solution, anyway. I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting within `sed` like this:

```
sed -n '/^'"$val1"'/,/^'"$val2"'/p;/^'"$val2"'/q' "$file"
```

You might think it's a lot of quotes, which it is, but that's likely your issue.

> - [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) is helpful in these situations.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work, i tried with and without in both file and variable :
val1="[TABLE]"
val2="[END_TABLE]"
sed -n '/^'"$val1"'/,/^'"$val2"'/p;/^'"$val2"'/q' "$file"

I give me not output